# Run QT5 app (chiaki remote play) on raspberry OS lite

Tags: qt

I would like to run Chiaki (Playstation Remote Play https://github.com/Fredrum/chiaki) on my raspberrypi zero WH running raspberrypiOS lite (so no GUI).

running chiaki itself on a raspberry pi(zero included) with a GUI is already possible
(https://github.com/Fredrum/chiaki/wiki/Chiaki-for-the-Raspberry-Pi).

What i would like to do tu run this app from an OS without GUI in a way that it open a full-screen window.

Is that possible?

i have already tried to run it and i get the following error:
"qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"

Comment: `run this app from an OS without GUI in a way that it open a full-screen window` ... this is unclear ... where does the full-screen window run?

Comment: This is what I’m trying to figure out. More in general is it possible to run a GUI app from raspberry OS lite?

Comment: It was at one time possible (and may still be) to compile qt to run on the [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).  You could dig into that, but I think it is not worthwhile (which is why I also think this was abandoned some years ago), because in the end it does not have much use value for the same reason I think there is a minor [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) in this:  What you really want is to run a fullscreen app without the clutter of taskbars and such, not necessarily "no GUI".

Comment: ...The GUI stack is layered (hence "stack"), with upper layers adding functionality but dependent on those beneath them. The bottom of this in userland is the Xorg server; without any of the layers on top it presents a blank screen with just a mouse cursor.  You can't do anything with it as a user, since the mouse buttons do nothing or near enough, and there is nothing to click on or control.

Comment: ...However, you can configure it to launch an app when it starts, in which case you do get a (potentially fullscreen) window (no frame or topbar tho).  Look around for stuff about creating a **kiosk** and you'll find a more detailed explanation.